# How to create protocol for the network layer on CAN bus?

Tags: microcontroller, can-bus, communication-protocol

I am using MCP 2515 integrated CAN controllers/transceivers and arduino microcontrollers connected to multiple sensors to create a CAN bus. I am now trying to create a network layer on top of the simple CAN messaging. The goal is to emulate a 1553 bus with CAN.

Can this simply be done with the use of masks and filters and a for loop that cycles through each controller to ask if there is data to be sent on a CAN bus shield? I have investigated the CANopen protocol, but I am unsure on how to even begin (generating PDOs/SDOs and creating the proper library).

Comment: I'm sure to have understood what your goal is but is you want to switch the physical layer of the 1553 bus with the one from the CAN bus, I think you would have to write a (completely ?) new library. If you want to mimic 1553 bus behavior (request/reply model) while using CAN bus, you can simply use masks and all.

Comment: To design a high layer CAN protocol is very qualified work, you need lots of CAN experience. If you are an Arduino hobbyist, start learning to crawl before anything else. For example, you don't send data through a shield... because... it's a shield, not a data line... In general, I would recommend to drop Arduino for something more useful with a built-in CAN controller. Pick your favourite flavour of Cortex M instead: ST, NXP, Renesas, Microchip etc etc.